# Eclipse Crash with Android Application Project when it uses the Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, sdk

Eclipse crashes when it uses the Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), I tried with the version of Eclipse "Android Developer" that comes with the folder, or with a standard version of Eclipse.

---

## Solved

EDIT: so I had to uninstall the JRE, reinstall it, and only download the ADT from Android webpage with Eclipse included, and it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I had to uninstall the JRE, reinstall it, and only download the ADT from Android webpage with Eclipse included, and it all works.